# why paging links does not display?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new in PHP Codeigniter. I am trying to apply paging in my web page for that I have used following code

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/admin/pages/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->pages_model->count_pages();
        $config['per_page'] = '1';
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<p>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</p>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);


        $pageData['records']=$this->pages_model->get_pages($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
```

in controller. In view I used following code`$this->pagination->create_links()`
But it does not shows the paging links.
The main problem is that class variable in Pagignation class $total_rows and $per_page could not be assigned . Its value remains default which is hard coded in Pagingnation.php file.I do not now what is the problem.
Is there any way to overcome this problem?

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you missing to `echo` it somewhere ?

Comment: I have written echo but then also there is no change!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting error reporting in your index.php file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
display_errors(1);
```

And maybe you'll get some errors that let you know whats wrong.

Comment: There's only one index.php in codeigniter. It's in your root directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you included pagination library `$this->load->library('pagination');`

Comment: have u passed ` $pageData['records']` to your view page?

Comment: Are you sure you have values in `$pageData['records']`. try `pirnt_r($pageData['records'])`; in controller and if values are coming try this in view page by `print_r($records)`;

Comment: yes I am sure. It is passed but the problem is that $total_row and $per_page remains unchanged in Pagingnation class

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one record, it won't show you the pagination. What's your value of `total_rows`?

If you want the pagination to behave in an other way than this, you'll either have to extend the library and remake `create_links()` or find an already created extension on the web that suits your needs more.

[Example to solve your issue](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/154919/#749876)

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = "///your url";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->user->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 1;//may vary
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;//may vary based on url segments
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $this->session->set_userdata('page',$page);
        $this->session->set_userdata('per_page',$config["per_page"]);
        $data["sposts"] = $this->user->post($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('post_view',$data);
```

This is the code for creating pagination in controller after loading pagination library.
Pagination library can be loaded in constructor or in a function as `$this->load->library("pagination");`.

Now in view file write this to create links

```
echo $links;
```